# Getting null values from include('1.php?id='.$id) file, PHP

Tags: php, mysql

included a php file for inserting values into table. script inserting values but all null.

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$id=$_GET['id'];
include_once ('1.php?id='.$id);

$sql = "insert into table ( ... ) values (variables from 1.php?id='.$id)";
```

insert query is fine but submitting null values.. what is wrong ?

Comment: Please be clear. What you want to do.

Comment: can you show  us `1.php`

Comment: What is submitting null values ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass `variable`s to files while including like `query string`s. If the `variable`s are set then they will already be available on those files you are including after that. Do -

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$id=$_GET['id'];
include_once ('1.php');

$sql = "insert into table ( name ) values ('$name')";
```

**1.php** 
Something like -

```
if(!empty($id)) { // Check if the variable is present
    // Genarate the variables
    $name = 'xyz';
}
```

Comment: if `$name` is a user (or dinamically) generated value, i recommend a more secure [approach](http://www.phptherightway.com/#pdo_extension) using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension

Comment: Yup. That should be taken care of. But not question related.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the following code snippet:

```
if(!empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
    include_once("1.php?id={$id}");
    $sql = "INSRET INTO your_table (your_columns)  VALUES (variables from 1.php?id={$id})";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```